# Is there a way to extract only the received emails from Gmail

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to extract incoming emails from gmail (well, Google Apps mail, but near enough) using IMAP. I want all good messages (not spam/deleted) even if they have been filed in different folders (so running through the Inbox is not sufficient), but I don't want messages sent from the current account, or drafts (both of which show up in the 'All Mail' folder).

This is for widespread use, so I can't just assume that there's only certain specific known folder names in addition to the Inbox to check.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Nope, this doesn't actually work properly. Working with another domain doesn't have the `[$]NOTJUNK` flags; my guess is that these are set by Apple Mail.

**/UPDATE**

The best result I've managed to get so far is to find the messages in the **AllMail** folder with the `$NOTJUNK` flag set, but the `NOTJUNK` (no $) flag unset and filter out the messages that are returned from the **Sent** folder.

From the brief testing I've done `NOTJUNK` was only set for draft messages (eg from Apple Mail, but not for drafts from within the web interface - in that case neither `NOTJUNK` nor `$NOTJUNK` were set)

Note: I'm using `xlist` to find the correct localised versions of these folders.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `NOTJUNK` flags seem unreliable, I'm now getting all messages from the **AllMail** folder, throwing away the ones from the **Sent** folder, and then throwing away the ones that *don't* have the `Delivered-To` header (I hope the drafts are the only ones without this header)